# jquery find() combine id and html element possible?

Tags: jquery, selector

just wondering:

in CSS I can access a div through

```
#display div
```

is there a similar way in Jquery. I need to find the DIV with id="displayFirst" (a page) and from within this DIV the div with data-role=content. Something along the lines of:

```
.find('#displayFirst', 'div[data-role=content]'));
```

Thanks,

Frequent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use a space (the [descendant selector](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/)) as your current selector does (just like CSS):

```
$('#displayFirst div[data-role=content]');
```

the same applies when using [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/):

```
.find('#displayFirst div[data-role=content]');
```